# In JQGrid how can I display context menu at left click?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu

Hy,

In my application I am using JQGrid tool for displaying the lists.

I need to show context menu on both left and right click (my client choice...). Is this possible?

For displaying the context menu on right click I am using the loadComplete function like this:

```
loadComplete: function () {
        $("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu('contextMenu', {
                bindings: {...},
                onContextMenu: function (event) {...}
            });
        },
```

and it's working fine.

For displaying the context menu on left click I've tried the beforeSelectRow function:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e){
        $("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu('contextMenu', {
                bindings: {...},
                onContextMenu: function (event) {...}
            });
        },
```

but it's not working!

Does anyone have any idea how can I show the context menu at left-click on the row (or maybe selecting the row, it's the same)?

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you just bind `click` event to the same event handler defined in the `jquery.contextmenu.js`. To do this you can use the following code

```js
var cmenu = $grid.data('events').contextmenu;
if (cmenu && cmenu.length > 0) {
    $grid.click(cmenu[0].handler);
}
```

I use the fixed version of `jquery.contextmenu.js` which now a part of jqGrid (see my suggestions [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-fixes-in-jquery-contextmenu-js-plugin/#p25321)). So I bound `contextMenu` not to every grid row, but to the grid element directly.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/InlineEditingInContextmenuOnClick.htm) shows that the above approach works. If you use additional bindings to `contextmenu` event you can improve the code above to choose the correct event handler `cmenu[i].handler`.

Comment: I've put the code as you showed me and as I saw in the demo source page, but nothing is happening and when I alert(cmenu) it shows undefined...

Comment: @JeffNorman: Which version of the `jquery.contextmenu.js` you use? How you bound the `contextmenu` and to which elements of the page (grid or it's rows)? You can see full code which I used, but I can't help you if I don't see the code which you use now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which is basically triggering a right click.

```
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e){
       console.log(this);
       console.log(rowid);
       $("tr.jqgrow", this).trigger({
           type: 'mousedown',
           which: 3
       });
    }
```

Comment: @Jeff - Can you check my edited answer? I have added couple of log messages. Let me know what you see.

Comment: I don't have firebug to see the logs, but I've put them on alert and it shows [object HTMLTableElement] and my row guid.

Comment: Can you select the `tr` element by row guid? Is it rendered as any attribute inside `tr` element?

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing from the above works on mine version of the grid if works then badly.**

The best thing that worked is just to edit the \trirand\plugins\jquery.contextmenu.js
file,

---

look for this row

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu', function (e)
```

and change or add to whatever you prefer, for example for left click do:

```
$(this).bind('click', function (e)
```

for double click do

```
$(this).bind('dblclick', function (e)
```

This worked like charm :-)